# Number of Sets of Partitions

Tags: integer-partitions

I looked at the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of numbers, like let's say $n=5$. You get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
5&=&5\\
\hline
&=&4+1\\
&=&3+2\\
\hline
&=&3+1+1\\
&=&1+2+2\\
\hline
&=&2+1+1+1\\
\hline
&=&1+1+1+1+1\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where I grouped the partitions according to their distribution (i.e. appearance) of summands. So you get $5$ sets.

Is it possible to get the number of sets for general $n$?

**ANOTHER EDIT, thanks to Brian**

If $\pi$ is a partition of $n$, let $M_\pi$ be the multiset of pieces, and let $\sigma_\pi$ be the sequence of multiplicities of $M_\pi$ listed in non-decreasing order. Then partitions $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are in the same set if $\sigma_\pi=\sigma_{\pi'}$. Thus, $\pi=1+3+3$ and $\pi'=2+2+3$ are in the same set, because $M_\pi=[1,3,3]$, so $\sigma_\pi=\langle 1,2\rangle$, and $M_{\pi'}=[2,2,3]$, so $\sigma_{\pi'}=\langle 1,2\rangle$ as well.

**EDIT**

Here's another example for $n=6$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
6 = 6\\
\hline
5 + 1 = 6\\
4 + 2 = 6\\
\hline
3 + 3 = 6\\
\hline
4 + 1 + 1 = 6\\
\hline
3 + 2 + 1 = 6\\
\hline
2 + 2 + 2 = 6\\
\hline
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6\\
\hline
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6\\
\hline
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6\\
\hline
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6
\end{eqnarray}
$$
so we have $10$ sets...

Comment: I do not know if i understand it quite well. But it seems to be $n$ sets. See the partitions that looks like $\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{\text{$k$ times}}+(n-k)$.

Comment: There is no nice closed form for the partition function, if that's what you're wondering.  There are many equivalent expressions, including the generating function.  There are approximate estimates, and other known properties.

Comment: @Brian Do you have any idea towards a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, there is no easy closed form for the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function) without any restrictions. However, given some restrictions, there are some nicer closed forms. For example, if we let a composition of $n$ be a partition of $n$ in which order matters, then let $P(n)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ which only use $1$ and $2$ as its parts and let $Q(n)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ which only use odd parts. Then, it can be easily proven that $P(n)=F_{n+1}$ and $Q(n)=F_n$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: it's clear from the example that **question is not about** [formula for] **the partition function**

Comment: @draks... Thanks and you're welcome!